# Format the color of a matplotlib line chart based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to create a plot where I display a time series that changes color according to the date.
For instance, all the observations in summer months have the same color, and all the observations in winter months have a different color, and so on.

This is the data frame that I am currently using:

```
Date Of Experience  Rating  Number of reviews
2009-04-01  5   1
2010-05-01  4   1
2010-08-01  5   2
2010-11-01  5   2
2010-12-01  3   1
... ... ...
2020-09-01  4   3
2020-10-01  1   1
```

Right now I have just created a basic line chart

```
plt.figure(figsize=(25,12), dpi= 80)
plt.plot(dates, CountofRatingsXDate['Number of reviews'])
xtick_location = dates.tolist()[::12]
xtick_labels = [x[0:7] for x in dates.tolist()[::12]]
plt.xticks(ticks=xtick_location, labels=xtick_labels, rotation=90, fontsize=12, horizontalalignment='center', alpha=.7)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df.sort_values(by='Dates', inplace=True)

color_dict = {
    'orange': ['2009-04-01', '2010-11-01'],
    'purple': ['2010-11-01', '2020-09-01'],
    'green': ['2020-09-01', '2020-10-01'],
}

plt.figure(figsize=(7, 2))
for color, date_range in color_dict.items():
    sns.lineplot(data=df[df.Dates.ge(date_range[0]) & df.Dates.le(date_range[1])],
                 x='Dates', y='Number_of_reviews', color=color, label=color)\
    .set_xticklabels(sorted(df.Dates), rotation=45, ha='right')
    
plt.title('My Title')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]